# Salesforce Commerce Cloud Ocapi

Tags: api, salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am working on the open commerce api on SFCC, I found out something weird and wanted to know why.
When making a get request from the Shop api, the Bearer is not compulsory but on all other requests (patch, post, put, delete...) the Bearer is required.
Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET requests only fetches data without any modification to the data. All other request methods are usually used to modify data in the backend:

```
POST -> Create resource
PUT -> Update resource with replace
PATCH -> Partially update resource
DELETE -> remove resource
```

Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

For that reason you have to authenticate with the OCAPI if you are using one of these methods.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, but then anyone could make a get request on my data no ? So then anyone could have access to my products / orders etc...

Comment: For endpoints that deliver data that is customer specific like baskets, orders etc. an authentication token is always required. You can also levarage the OCAPI settings in BM to provide access only to certain resources and define CORS access (see [SFCC Ocapi Settings](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/usage/OCAPISettings.html?cp=0_15_2_24) and [SFCC Ocapi CORS](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/usage/CORS.html?cp=0_15_2_5)).